# Get Worksheet_change event to execute macro automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro (ApplyFilter) that filters through many worksheets based on a date I enter into cell B1 on another worksheet (Grand Totals). That macro is:

```
Sub ApplyFilter() 'Filters all worksheets except worksheet1 for date entered into _
                  'Grand Totals!B1
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim FilterRange As Variant
FilterRange = Range("'Grand Totals'!B1")
' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
' workbook.
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
' Begin the loop.
    For I = 2 To WS_Count
    Sheets(I).Select
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False 'Remove any existing filters
    Worksheets(I).Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("'Grand Totals'!B1").Text
    Next I
Sheet1.Activate
End Sub
```

When I execute this macro manually, it executes and filters as it should. However, when I call this macro from another sub:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then _
    Call ApplyFilter
End Sub
```

I get a "Macros" window that offers a list of macros available. I can select the "ApplyFilter" macro and click Run and the Macro executes and filters the worksheets as I desire.

I found many references to automatically executing a macro from within a sub, but none refer to the "Macros" window, from which I now must select the macro to run. Instead, when I enter a date in cell B1 of the "Grand Totals" worksheet and hit enter, sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range) should automatically call "ApplyFilter" and apply the date filter to the many worksheets.

I have created a button and used Button_Click to call "ApplyFilter", and all is well. But, it seems more intuitive to enter the date and then press Enter to execute the macro. I could put up with the Button_Click method, but I'm trying to learn VBA firstly, and I'm just stubborn enough to want to learn how to make it work, and I do not want settle just for what will work.

Comment: This should work as is - presuming that you do have this code `Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` **inside** the sheet code of 'Grand Totals`?  (right click sheet tab, View Code, then copy and paste this event in there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheet Code must be in `Grand Totals` sheet

- right click your `Grand Totals` sheet tab
- `View Code`
- Ensure the code below is pasted in here
- [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)[f11](/questions/tagged/f11) back to Excel

**Grand Totals Sheet Code**

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then Call ApplyFilter
End Sub
```

**more efficient filter code**

```
Sub ApplyFilter()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      If ws.Name <> "Grand Totals" Then
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        ws.Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("'Grand Totals'!B1").Text
      End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: During my research on your site yesterday, I discovered that the code needed to be in the sheet code, so I placed it there, but it still didn't work. Today, before I changed the code (just eliminated the continuation underscore) as you suggested, it ran! Yesterday, the same code would not run; perhaps rebooting and reloading Excel helped solve the problem; I don't know. I certainly appreciate the comments about "more efficient filter code", part of this exercise was to learn more about VBA. Thanks very much. You have a great site, here; I've learned a lot.